# How can I find a laptop if it has a different model name all over the world?

Tags: laptop, specifications

CONUNDRUM: A laptop review in the UK talks about how brilliant the "ASUS ABCDE 55" is, but in America, France, etc there is no such laptop name. In fact it's called "ASUS 12345 AB" - AAARRGH!

QUESTION: Is there a way of finding out all the diverse names for the same laptop all over the world?

Example: if Samsung create a R2D2500, then what is that spec laptop called in all the other countries (if they release it of course). Or if it's not released, what is their similar spec laptop called in the other countries?

I understand that specs may be different, but if I read a review on my trusted UK website, but live in say Australia, I want to be able to find the name of the same laptop in Australia and then check out local places to buy it.

So if anyone knows if there is a technique, specific website, or even how to use a company website to find out these annoying name changes I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I think by "name" you mean "model name".

Comment: if samsung made an R2D2-500 i'd totally wait until the R2D2-TX came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is there's no simple way to find it. You have to do your research in each specific situation and each manufacturer / company will behave differently with that.

Apple, for instance, use always the same model name all over the world. I believe Dell do it so too. Actually, I didn't even know there is any company that don't do that, but I can understand how it happens. Lack of support and standard on the company itself can easily lead to that, specially small local companies that just assembly the parts together into any generic device.

That being said, Google is your friend. But look first for the company website, then for local reviewing sites, or vending / auctioning. eBay is also a good source for identifying.